# Unable to use git-svn in Mac

Tags: svn, git, macos, macports

I installed Git with svn in MacPorts by

```
sudo port install git-core +svn
```

I have tried to use git-svn unsuccessfully by

```
git svn egUrl
```

and

```
git-svn egUrl
```

**How can you use Git-svn in Mac** after MacPorts' installation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to start by cloning a Svn repository into git. In my case, I use the following (my git-core is v1.6.x):

`git svn clone https://myrepos.com/project -T trunk -b branches/*/* --prefix=svn/`

The cloning may take a while, but once complete, you'll be able to interact with your new git repository using git commands and then pull/commit to svn using `git svn rebase` and `git svn dcommit`, respectively.

This is a bit high level and doesn't offer much detail, but hopefully it will at least get you started.

Comment: be careful with this one.  If you are managing a Continuous integration SVN repository under branches, it will take hours to clone all of your release branches.  I'd recommend `git svn clone https://myrepos.com/project/trunk` or direct path to dev branch for starters.

Answer (score 3):

Don’t forget to `git init` your directory before calling `git svn init`.